Discrepancy between Google Analytics API data and analytics website data despite correct API query aggregation
I've been encountering an issue while working with the Google Analytics API. Despite correctly querying the API and aggregating the metrics with the corresponding dimensions provided by the API response, I've noticed that the data retrieved from the API doesn't match the data displayed on the Google Analytics website.
I'm using the Google Analytics Reporting API to retrieve data for a specific date range and dimension.
I'm aggregating the metrics from the API response using the dimensions provided (such as date).
However, even after summing the values from every entry with the dimension provided by the API response, the aggregated metrics still don't match the data displayed on the Google Analytics website for the same date range and dimension.
I've double-checked my API query parameters and ensured they match the settings on the analytics website.
Even using the query explorer the data does not match, for example:
Using this params:
query explorer params
The results are the following:
query explorer results
The metric aggregation result from sessions does match with the one showed in the analytics website but when adding all the sessions from records one by one the results are different, the result from adding sessions from records is 135,992 which is far from the shown in the website and the metric aggregate from the response.
I have tried using different dimensions and the results are different but not even similar to the website.
I have the same problem with different metrics like users, sessions, pageviews, etc.
I also tried using the .NET API Client from Google Analytics with the same result.
Has anyone else experienced similar discrepancies between Google Analytics API data and the data displayed on the analytics website? Are there any additional considerations or steps I should take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is not about programming or software development. You should delete it and ask to the  Stack Exchange Webmasters' community where web experts are ready to help.
